# trying to colour dates in ui bootstrap calendar after ajax call

Tags: angularjs, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

my html code of calendar:

```
              .appointment>button {
                color: black;
                background-color: red;
              }

               .holidays>button {
                color: black;
                background-color: green;
              }

            </style>

<uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" class="well well-sm" datepicker-options="inlineOptions" ng-change="dateSelected()" date-disabled="enableRequired(date, mode)" custom-class="colourClass(date, mode);"></uib-datepicker>
```

my angularjs controller code:

```
     holidays = new Array();

    var promise = servicePOST.send(appConstants.BASE_MS_URL + 'Dcrs/activityDay.php',{
            "date":d
        }).then(function(result) {
            $scope.dcrlocked = result.dcrlocked;
            $scope.leaves = result.leaves; 
            console.log(result.holidays);
            //$scope.holidays = result.holidays; 
             for(i=0;i<result.holidays.length;i++)
         {
            holidays.push(new Date(result.holidays[i].date.replace(/-/g,',')));
         }   

        alert(holidays.length);
            return result.holidays;
        });

     promise.then(function(result) {
        alert("holiday length after service post"+holidays.length);

         $scope.colourClass = function(date, mode) {

                if (mode === 'day') {

                  var dateToCheck = new Date(date);

                    for(var i = 0; i < holidays.length ; i++) {
                    if(areDatesEqual(holidays[i], dateToCheck)){
                      return 'appointment';
                    }
                  }


                }
                return '';
              };

    });
```

what happens now is that the colours don't get displayed! the $q is injected and the result fetched of the holidays array length is proper but now the only thing is that the colours dont get displayed! i wonder why! any help would be appreciated!